# Is it possible to remove new google hangouts app's white background?

Tags: google-chrome, google

I installed the new hangouts app it would look awesome but this white background ruins its design. Is it possible to remove it and make it transparent as it looks on chromebook?
You can download the app here: http://www.google.com/hangouts/

[image]

Comment: i found the .css files of this app here 

/home/<USER>/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl/2014.1007.433.6_0/styles 

i tried to modify panel.css file but nothing changed. Maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: it seems chrome isn't compiled to support transparency, so the rgba css won't have an effect

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because of limitations on Linux...

Comment: Umpf, Hangouts App? Link?

Comment: @A.B. it's in question description :-) to launch it use Dash.

Comment: I know that it is transparent on two of my friends' systems, so obviously it was intended to be transparent. I'll try and see if I can grab their config and look for differences. However, my hangouts is completely different from yours and my friends, looking like this: https://tariqsheikhweb.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/unnamed.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible, there aren't any animations either. [As stated by the Hangouts PM.](https://plus.google.com/+MayurKamat/posts/XgBCs3nTUC2)